# How to convert a cell array of 'True' and 'False' values to logical values?

Tags: matlab

MATLAB has logical values `true` and `false`, but in my cell array I have the strings `'True'` and `'False'`. What is the best way to convert these to the logical values `true` and `false`?

Comment: You have the characters 'T' and 'F'? Have you tried `M=='T'` where M is your matrix?

Comment: I have matrix with "True' or 'False' string.

Comment: That can't be a matrix. Is it a 2D cell array of strings?

Comment: you are right. It is 2D cell array. not a matrix. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what the format of your input is.

If you have a character array of `'T'` and `'F'` characters, you can just use

```
output = input == 'T';
```

If you have a cell array of `'T'` and `'F'` characters you can use strcmpi

```
output = strcmpi(input, 'T');
```

Or if you have the strings `'True'` or `'False'` in a cell array you can *also* use `strcmpi`

```
output = strcmpi(input, 'True');
```

Comment: It is 'True' or 'False'. Your solution worked for me. Thanks a lot.